# Can we store "cd .." path in a variable in bash file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to the bash my use case is to store the one previous directory in to a variable.

Example:

```
DIR='/local/example/'
```

How  can we add `/local/` to any variable like `$PREV`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion on $PWD which contains the current path:

```
dir=${PWD%/*}  # Remove everything from the last / forward.
```

Or, use an external tool like readlink with command substitution:

```
dir=$(readlink -f ..)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dirname`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dirname.1.html) to strip the last component from a path:

```sh
dir=/local/example
prev=$(dirname "$dir")
```

sets `prev` to `/local`

Answer (score 0):

```
pwd | awk -F\/ '{ print "/"$(NF-1)"/" }'
```

Split separate the output of pwd using awk using "/" as the field delimiter/ Print the last but one field appended with "/" and with "/" following.